# What do you call a person who takes a survey?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

The person who conducts a survey is called a Surveyor.
What do we call the people who take the survey and answer the questions?

Comment: The [people making up the] sample.

Comment: ***Surveyee***: A person who is subject to a survey.

Comment: @Josh, Can you provide a source? I can't find any that are credible. However, a person who is subject to a survey, is a **subject**. *Note*, I can't find any sources for this either, which is why it's a comment. :)

Comment: @Chris Wohlert  My team is doing a Presentation on 'Designing of Questionnaire' for conducting surveys. The term 'Surveyee' solved my problem. Thank You.

Comment: Does "survey-taker" count as one word?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm not sure that those who conduct surveys of the *questionnaire* sort are called [*surveyors*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/surveyor) (try [*pollster*](http://www.eudict.com/?lang=en2eng&word=one%20who%20conducts%20surveys,%20one%20who%20conducts%20a%20poll,%20somebody%20conducting%20a%20poll) instead), but you can call the ones who take the survey *respondents*.

> **Respondent** *noun*
>   2 A person who replies to something, especially one supplying information for a questionnaire or responding to an advertisement.
>   ‘most respondents to our questionnaire considered their practices to be in accordance with current medical guidelines’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/respondent)

See also the following entry from the same page:

> **Respondent** *adjective*
>   2 [attributive] Replying to something.
>   ‘the respondent firms in the survey’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/respondent)

Here are some examples of the term in use:

- Why do People Participate as Respondents in a Survey?
  [- Scott Smith, Qualtrics](https://www.qualtrics.com/blog/why-do-people-participate-as-respondents-in-a-survey/)
- 5 Easy Ways to Avoid Survey Fatigue in Your Respondents
  [- Andrea Fryrear, Survey Gizmo](https://www.surveygizmo.com/survey-blog/5-basic-ways-to-avoid-survey-fatigue/)

Comment: Hi Lawrence, Thank you. The word respondent also serves my purpose like the word Surveyee. Though Surveyee is not in Oxford Dictionary, It is in usage. And thanks for the correction(Surveyor). So, What would be the suitable word to call a person who conducts a survey?

Comment: @Sivani You're welcome. Try *pollster* for the person who conducts a survey.

Comment: For completeness, a person who performs the _other_ kind of survey, namely measuring land to set legal boundaries, or before aerial photography to create accurate maps, _is_ correctly called a 'surveyor'.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yes, quite so. I've amended my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 7):

The first word I thought of for this was *participant*

A [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=survey%20participants&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) indicates that others use this term, as well as *respondent* as suggested by [Lawrence](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/142322/lawrence)

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that the term ***[surveyee](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/surveyee)***, though not present in dictionaries, is used with  meaning of:

> - a person who is subject to a survey.

The are numerous usage examples from academic sources:

From [Business Statistics](https://books.google.it/books?id=FCOZgjsK1ycC&pg=PA404&dq=%22surveyee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXuLOU-qjSAhUFwxQKHS0xAbgQ6AEIJDAC#v=onepage&q=%22surveyee%22&f=false):

> - "It is useful when evaluating a survey that tests ***which option the surveyee prefers,*** but not by how much."

From [Journal of high technology management research](https://books.google.it/books?id=b4IWddyrYi0C&q=%22surveyee%22&dq=%22surveyee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig2d3Y_ajSAhXTKywKHX5DDI84ChDoAQgZMAA):

> - "Both a structured and open-ended approach was applied to questions and interviews. Surveying was structured so each question had a number of predetermined responses ***from which the surveyee could choose***. In this way all companies ..."

From [Impact of Increased Environmental Awareness on the Supermarket Industry:](https://books.google.it/books?id=fhVIAAAAYAAJ&q=%22surveyee%22&dq=%22surveyee%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig2d3Y_ajSAhXTKywKHX5DDI84ChDoAQgpMAQ)

> - ... *"the interviewer approached another customer.If the customer consented to participate, then the surveyer asked them the questions. ***After the survey was complete the surveyee was asked to complete demographic information on their own***."

Comment: Wasn't the question what the people are called who answer the questions?