# What do you call the person asking someone survey questions and recording that person's answers?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call the person who completes a survey for another person?

Example:

John Doe goes to some supermarket and buys some food. Marie, who works at the quality assurance department of the supermarket, calls John and asks him a series of questions about the food he's just bought (a survey about the food).

In this case, Marie is filling out the survey in name of John about the food he bought. What should I call Marie?

Comment: Hi, welcome to EL&U! I'm not quite sure what you're asking; you've got three variables in your example (A, X, & Y) and from your title I think you want to ask about A, but then your question asks about X and Y (and first you call X a topic, then a person). Could you edit your question to clarify? It will help a lot, and is technically required for this kind of question, if you make up a full example sentence showing how you want to use the word. Put a ___ or other placeholder where you want the word to go. You should also have a look at our Help pages to learn more about EL&U. Good luck!

Comment: @1006a Thanks for your feedback, I added an example, hope it is useful. Sorry for my bad English tho

Comment: After the edit there are only two people. Marie, who works for the supermarket, and Jhon, who she has called to take part in the survey. Marie is filling in the form with the answers to questions she is asking Jhon. So a name for Marie could be "questioner", or "survey manager" etc.

Comment: The question is completely different from how I imagined it. Good job in clarifying the points!

Comment: That edit is very helpful, thanks! A related post (not a duplicate, though the accepted answer does suggest a possible answer to your question as an aside): [What do you call a person who takes a survey?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/375271/177853)

Comment: @1006a why isn't it a duplicate? I have the dupe hammer btw.

Comment: This question is about the role of "Marie", that one is about the role of "John". There's just a footnote suggestion of an answer to this question (about Marie's role), which hasn't been properly voted on (presumably votes on that answer are based on how well it answers the actual question), and there aren't any other competing answers about Marie's role, since it wasn't asked about there. @Mari-LouA

Comment: @1006a but the answers of John are being recorded by Marie, this is what people polling always do, they write the "responses", the people interviewing fill in the forms and then (sometimes) they ask the the member of public to sign it. I had originally thought of a delegate but it's clear that is not the answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think in this case there are three "parties" to the transaction with distinct roles: the party that wants the research done (the grocery store, in the example), the party hired to conduct that research (Marie), and the subjects of the research (John, plus of course any other customers who are surveyed). The OP in the linked question was asking about the word for the "subject" role, this OP wants to know about the word for the "hired conductor" role.

Comment: Surveys are usually filled out by respondents or takers They are not usually filled out by third parties on behalf of the respondent. So, person filling out the survey. In some cases, proxy respondents, but not here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Marie, the person asking would be best known as

[**a canvasser**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/canvasser?topic=questioning-people-and-asking-questions-in-general)

> a person who tries to discover information or opinions by asking people:
>
> - Canvassers surveyed people from over 2,500 households.
> - He instructs canvassers on how to elicit honest information.

[**a questioner**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/questioner)

> a person who asks a question

possibly [**an inquirer or enquirer**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inquirer)

> someone who asks about something

**Note that canvasser, questioner, inquirer (enquirer) have other meanings in different contexts.**

For example,

a canvasser can also mean someone campaigning on behalf of a political candidate.

a questioner can mean a person who feels or expresses doubt about something.

an inquirer can mean someone that is involved in investigating incidents, e.g., a parliamentary inquiry into corruption

**A good equivalent term** to canvasser **would be** [**pollster**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pollster) **as suggested by** [**Lawrence**](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/142322/lawrence) in the answer to the [**What do you call a person who takes a survey?**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/375271/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-takes-a-survey) question pointed out by [**1006a**](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/177853/1006a)

> a person whose job is to ask people their opinions on a subject, as part of a poll (= opinion study)

**I agree with** [**Lawrence**](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/142322/lawrence) when he points out that **surveyor** mentioned by OP in that question **is not appropriate**

To my knowledge [**surveyor**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/surveyor#h47168239725740) refers to

> A person who examines the condition of land and buildings professionally.
>
> 1.1 British An official inspector of something, especially for measurement and valuation purposes.
>
> - ‘surveyors recorded the species and locations of fallen trees’
>
> 1.2 A person who investigates or examines something, especially boats for seaworthiness.
>
> - ‘a marine surveyor’

Also, in my opinion, (limited experience) [**surveyee**](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/surveyee) given as an alternative term for John's role in your question is not commonly used.

John would be known as a [**respondent**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/respondent)

> someone who responds to a question or offer:
>
> - Most respondents in the survey voiced an unfavorable attitude toward the policy.

Comment: I don't think OP is asking what we call "someone who responds to a question or offer". It seems to be specifically *someone who provides such responses **on behalf of another***.

Comment: Sorry @FumbleFingers, I beg to differ _**Marie, who works at the quality assurance department of the supermarket, calls John and asks him a series of questions about the food he's just bought** (a survey about the food)._

Comment: John's bought the food, Marie is merely noting his responses to her questions. I agree that the title is misleading.

Comment: Sorry - my mistake. I've cancelled my inappropriate downvote. But yeah - at least we can agree there was *some* justification for me being "misled". Though I must admit that mostly I just wasn't paying enough attention when I read the question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you. I appreciate your candour :P The question was edited several times before consensus was reached on what OP was asking, Getting our wires crossed was to be expected under the circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

a **surveyor**. [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/surveyor)

> someone who conducts a statistical survey

As in:

As a **surveyor**, Marie is conducting the questionnaire of John about the food he bought.

Comment: This usage is obviously problematic.